Coming up to PhD oral, one examiner doesn't like my work
I have all three examiner reports, one from overseas, one from a different university in my country, and one from my university. My PhD work is in STEM, with a large component of programming.
The overseas examiner really likes my work, and thinks I have made a contribution. He is in a different speciality to the other two. The one from the same country, but not my university, and thinks my work is technically impressive, but needs some work - basically reframing some parts and adding a bit more explanation.
The reviewer from my own university pretty much hates it, and wants me to do more work - major changes. He also thinks my work is technically good.
Is this usual? I am incredibly stressed ahead of my oral.

Am I correct to assume that none of these three is your advisor?

"Is this usual?" is not a good question because obviously this depends on what is in the thesis, which we don't know. Also these things depend a lot on the subject and also country. Disagreement between examiners is fairly common. Otherwise it isn't really clear what you are asking.

@Buffy yes, none of the examiners are permitted to be my advisors. I am also not allowed to discuss the reviewer feedback with my supervisors ahead of my oral.

@ChristianHennig I'm in the situation where I have: 1 reviewer says pass, or with minor changes, 1 reviewer says pass, but you need to make these changes, the 3rd reviewer seems to be - I can't see why this is a PhD.

It doesn’t matter whether this is "usual". What matters is how you (can) deal with it. Both good and bad situations can be usual or unusual.

Well it is a PhD defense, not a coronation. You have to address their concerns and defend your findings. If you cannot stand behind your work, and do not know enough to defend it, do you deserve a PhD? You are the expert, go prove it.

I don't know what system is being used, so I can only answer for the UK, however, in the UK it would be unusual to see the reports before the exam.
In the UK its almost unheard of to pass your oral without corrections. The discussion is usually minor corrections (takes less than 3 months, requires only written work, no new research) or major corrections (takes more than 3 months, may require new research, but doesn't require a new exam), or resubmit (generally up to a new, needs a new exam).
The questions we as examiners have to answer are:

Is the work the candidates own.
Does the work show evidence of systematic study and of the ability to relate the results of such study to the general body of knowledge in the subject.
Does the work make at least one substantive addition to knowledge in the field.
Is the work suitable for publication, in full or abridged form.

In the time I have been an examiner I think the split between major and minor corrections is pretty much 50:50. Remember that last criteria, and then remember that almost no papers are published without a second round of peer review.

What I don't think is usual is your statement in a comment, that you aren't allowed to discuss these reports with your supervisor. And, given that, it may not be allowed for your supervisor to lobby with this other faculty member on your behalf. I also don't know what happens at the oral presentation. If your advisor can be present they can speak for you then, perhaps, if necessary. And, perhaps the other two reviewers can convince the third to soften their stance. But that is out of your hands, I'll guess.
I also don't know if unanimous consent is required for you to get the degree. If it is, then you may just be stuck and I don't see a way out.
I also don't know who chose the reviewers, or on what basis, or on what opportunities you might have had to avoid this situation via dealing with their concerns before this stage. Even the relative seniority of the reviewers and your advisor might play a part.
Some places, such as where I retired from, a negative vote wasn't final, but other places it is. Overall, I'd guess you are in a bad spot unless the system provides some way out. FWIW, I think it is unfair.
It might be permitted under the rules for you to ask your advisor to speak with this local faculty member and ask what they think. You don't have to discuss their report to make such a request.
For the oral itself, prepare yourself as best you can to answer questions and defend your methods and results, especially (especially) from this "dissenting" reviewer. That can make a difference.

It is usual, in some countries and some academic systems, that the supervisor must not be involved in the PhD defence process.

@Dilworth, that is a bit different from the advisor and the student discussing the situation as known.

Overall, I think that you are in a good standing, according to your description. All the reviewers think you made good technical contributions. One thinks you should do a bit more, but the others don't. Is it "usual"? I think it is: if you have three reviewers it is usual that some may be less favourable, while others are more.
You should simply defend politely your contributions. The worst case is that you may need to do some minor additions or corrections, and this is vastly "usual". Very few dissertations are accepted without modifications.
